# Mapstruct Bug with nested mapper and unmappedSourcePolicy

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I want to map a `EmployeeDto` to a `EmployeeValue`. Consider the following classes:

```
public class EmployeeDto {

    private String telephoneNumber;
    private Integer companyId;

    public String getTelephoneNumber() {
        return telephoneNumber;
    }

    public void setTelephoneNumber(String telephoneNumber) {
        this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
    }


    public Integer getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Integer companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

}


public class EmployeeValue {

    private String telephoneNumber;
    private Company company;

    public String getTelephoneNumber() {
        return telephoneNumber;
    }

    public void setTelephoneNumber(String telephoneNumber) {
        this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

}


public class Company {

    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I am trying to map those classes using a mapstruct-mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public interface EmployeeDto2EmployeeValueMapper {

    @Mapping(source ="companyId", target = "company.id")
    EmployeeValue map(EmployeeDto dto);

}
```

This is working just perfectly fine, as this test runs green:

```
class EmployeeDto2EmployeeValueMapperTest {

    private static final String TELEPHONE_NUMBER = "telephoneNumber";
    private static final int COMPANY_ID = 1;

    private EmployeeDto2EmployeeValueMapper classUnderTest = Mappers.getMapper(EmployeeDto2EmployeeValueMapper.class);

    @Test
    void map() {
        EmployeeDto employeeDto = new EmployeeDto();
        employeeDto.setTelephoneNumber(TELEPHONE_NUMBER);
        employeeDto.setCompanyId(COMPANY_ID);

        EmployeeValue outcome = classUnderTest.map(employeeDto);

        assertThat(outcome.getTelephoneNumber(), is(TELEPHONE_NUMBER));
        assertThat(outcome.getCompany().getId(), is(COMPANY_ID));
    }

}
```

Now, if I add `unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR` to the mapper, that is

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface EmployeeDto2EmployeeValueMapper {

    @Mapping(source ="companyId", target = "company.id")
    EmployeeValue map(EmployeeDto dto);

}
```

the build fails with the following error message:
Unmapped source properties: "telephoneNumber".

To me this seems like a bug, because those field actually got mapped (as my test proved before).
Do you have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to the mapstruct issue tracker the following entry seems to cover your question.

Issue: unmappedSourcePolicy set to ERROR leads to a nested Bean issue #1881

https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1881

According to issue comments a fix will be included in the upcoming release 1.4.0. However, I could not discover when this release will happen.